# WSO2 API Manager 1.10 Throttling tier limits are not performing properly in a gateway cluster setup

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, throttling, api-manager

We are using wso2am-1.10.0 with a gateway cluster. The throttling tier limits are not behaving as expected.

We have redefined the “Bronze” tier to allow 3 requests in 1 minute. The application is set to “Large”, the subscription to the API is set to “Bronze” and the resource is set to “Unlimited” . We understand that “Bronze” is the most restrictive tier in this case.

We have tested the API with and without a load-balancer:

With load-balancer:
We are always allowed to exceed the 3 requests by minute and then the throttling behaviour became inconsistent. Although it does not seem to be a multiple of the number of gateway workers.

Without load-balancer:
We call our API directly through a gateway worker of our cluster, the worker allows 4 requests(app-tier limit + 1) before returning a quota failure. Then if we call this API, within the same minute, but through an other gateway worker of our cluster, this worker allows one request before failing because of the quota limit.

We have tested the API without clustering the gateways and it works as expected.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We can't 100% guarantee on throttling on a cluster in API Manager 1.10, since we have to sync the servers. Throttling in a cluster was enhanced from API Manager 2.1 with a profile called [Traffic Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Product+Profiles). For single node API Manager, it will work perfectly.